# Include method in Ruby applied on an Array

Tags: arrays, ruby, methods

I am having some trouble with the include? method in ruby. As I understand this method should return true if the array includes the specified element. Like this:

```
a = [ "a", "b", "c" ]
a.include?("b")   #=> true
a.include?("z")   #=> false`
```

But when I do this :

```
soap_opera = ["all", "my", "children"]
p soap_opera.include?("a")
```

It returns false. Why?

Answer (score 4):

> I am having some trouble with the include? method in ruby. As I understand this method should return true if the array includes the specified element.

That is correct.

> But when I do this :
>
> ```rb
> soap_opera = ["all", "my", "children"]
> p soap_opera.include?("a")
> ```
>
> It returns false. Why?

Because, as you said above:

> this method should return true if the array includes the specified element

And `soap_opera` odes not contain the element `"a"`. `soap_opera` contains three elements, `"all"`, `"my"`, and `"children"`. `"a"` is not among them.

Answer (score 4):

As already explained it's because your array of strings does not include the string `'a'`.

For the result to be `true`, the array should list also the string `'a'`, **for example**:

```
ary = ['not', 'a', 'dog']
ary.include? 'a' #=> true
```

---

If you want to check **if any** of the strings of the array conteins the substring `'a'`, then you can use [Enumerable#any?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F):

```
ary = ["all", "my", "children"]
ary.any? { |str| str.include? 'a' } #=> true
```

---

While if you want to check **if all** of the strings contain the substring `'a'`, then you can use [Enumerable#all?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F):

```
ary = ["all", "my", "children"]
ary.all? { |str| str.include? 'a' } #=> false
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the character "a"? If you are, you can try this:

```
joined_soap_opera = soap_opera.join #  => "allmychildren" 

joined_soap_opera.include?("a") #  => true
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're confusing [`Array#include?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-include-3F) and [`String#include?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/String.html#method-i-include-3F)

Instead of checking the entire array, you can check each element individually:

```
oap_opera = ["all", "my", "children"]

oap_opera.each do |element|
  if element.include?("a")
    puts "'#{element}' includes 'a'"
  else
    puts "'#{element}' does not include 'a'"
  end
end
```

Prints

```
'all' includes 'a'
'my' does not include 'a'
'children' does not include 'a'
```